# Scheme - Lagrange's four-square theorem

Tags: math, lambda, functional-programming, scheme

I try to implement a function that computes the Lagrange's four-square theorem with a natural number n in scheme. However I haven't any idea to do that... Can someone give me a example/code please?

For example, a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = n, where n is the input of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with two functions (main & auxiliary):

If n is natural, (lagrange n) gives the list of all the quadruplets (a, b, c, d) such as  a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = n.

```
(define lagrange
  (lambda (n)
    (lagrange-aux 4 0 n)))

(define lagrange-aux
  (lambda (size m sum)
    (cond ((and (zero? size) (zero? sum)) '(()))
          ((or (zero? size) (> (* m m) sum)) '())
          (else (append (map (lambda (x) (cons m x))
                             (lagrange-aux (- size 1) 0 (- sum (* m m))))
                        (lagrange-aux size (+ m 1) sum))))))
```

Example:

```
(lagrange 13) ==>
((0 0 2 3) (0 0 3 2) (0 2 0 3) (0 2 3 0) (0 3 0 2) (0 3 2 0)
 (1 2 2 2) (2 0 0 3) (2 0 3 0) (2 1 2 2) (2 2 1 2) (2 2 2 1)
 (2 3 0 0) (3 0 0 2) (3 0 2 0) (3 2 0 0))
```